# C: I got a hard situation in data structure practice

Tags: c, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int row;  //행번호
    int col;   //열번호
    int value; //값
}element;

typedef struct ListNode {
    element data;
    struct ListNode *link;
}ListNode;

typedef struct {
    int rows;//행의 갯수
    int cols;//열의 개수
    ListNode *head;//연결리스트의 시작
    ListNode *tail;//연결리스트의 끝. 문제에 따라 사용할 건지는 본인이 선택
}ListHeader;

void init(ListHeader *plist, int r, int c)
{
    plist->rows = r;
    plist->cols = c;
    plist->head = NULL;
    plist->tail = NULL;
}
void print_matrix(ListHeader *plist)
{
    ListNode *p = plist->head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", p->data.row, p->data.col, p->data.value);
        p = p->link;
    }
}

void insert_node_last(ListHeader *plist, element a)
{
    ListNode *temp = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "메모리 할당 에러\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (a.row > plist->rows || a.col > plist->cols) {
        fprintf(stderr, "주어진 행 열 보다 큽니다.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    temp->data = a;
    temp->link = NULL;

    if (plist->tail == NULL) {
        plist->head = plist->tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        plist->tail->link = temp;
        plist->tail = temp;
    }
}

ListNode *add_sparse_maxtrix(ListHeader *plist1, ListHeader *plist2)
{
    ListNode *temp1 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *temp2 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *temp3 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    temp1 = plist1, temp2 = plist2;

    init(&temp3, (plist1->rows > plist2->rows ? plist1->rows: plist2->rows), (plist1->cols > plist2->cols ? plist1->cols : plist2->cols));          //temp3을 초기화 할때 두개의 리스트 중 큰 행과 열을 초기 행열로 줌

    while (temp1 != NULL && temp2 != NULL)
    {
        if (temp1->data.col == temp2->data.col && temp1->data.row == temp2->data.row) //행, 열이 같을때 값을 더한다. col = 열 row = 행
        {

            temp3->data.value = temp1->data.value + temp2->data.value;      //temp3 데이터 밸류에 temp1, temp2 밸류값 더해서 넣기
            temp3->data.col = temp1->data.col;                              //temp3 데이터 col(열)에 temp1 (temp2와 같음) 열 값 넣기
            temp3->data.row = temp1->data.row;                              //temp3 데이터 row(열)에 temp1 (temp2와 같음) 행 값 넣기
            insert_node_last(&temp3, temp3->data);                          //temp3에 새 노드 추가
            temp1 = temp1->link, temp2 = temp2->link;                       //temp1, temp2 다음 노드로 이동
        }
    /*
        else if (temp1->data.row == temp2->data.row && temp1->data.col > temp2->data.col) //행은 같고 열이 다를때 1 ex 0행 1열, 0행 2열...
    {

    }

        else if (temp1->data.row == temp2->data.row && temp1->data.col < temp2->data.col) //행은 같고 열이 다를때 2
        {

        }
    */
    temp1 = temp1->link, temp2 = temp2->link;
    }
return temp3;
}

void main()
{
    ListHeader list1;
    ListHeader list2;

    init(&list1, 6, 6);
    init(&list2, 4, 4);

    //다음과 같은 방법으로 행렬 A를 입력하시오
    element x = { 0,0,2 };                  //0행 0열에 2값을 가진 속성
    insert_node_last(&list1, x);            //마지막 노드에 

    element x2 = { 5,1,3 };
    insert_node_last(&list1, x2);

    element x3 = {4,2,4 };
    insert_node_last(&list1, x3); //여기 까지 list1 원소

    element x4 = { 0,3,5 };
    insert_node_last(&list2, x4);
    element x5 = { 3,4,6 };
    insert_node_last(&list2, x5); //여기까지 list2 원소




                                  //순서를 지켜서 입력
    print_matrix(&list1);
    print_matrix(&list2);
    //......그 다음일 수행


    add_sparse_maxtrix(&list1, &list2);

}
```

sorry for using korean in code comment and garbage english level.

this code is about add two sparse matrix, using linked list.

coding function init, print_matrix, insert_node_last was easy.

but add_sparse_maxtrix is really complecated.

i want to add plist1, plist2's element in different case.

and put it in the new node.

the cases are

1. plist1 row == plist2 row && plist1 col == plist2 col
2. plist1 row == plist2 row && plist1 col > plist2 col
3. plist1 row == plist2 row && plist1 col < plist2 col
4. plist1 row > plist2 row && plist1 col > plist2 col
5. plist1 row > plist2 row && plist1 col == plist2 col
6. plist1 row > plist2 row && plist1 col < plist2 col
7. plist1 row < plist2 row && plist1 col > plist2 col
8. plist1 row < plist2 row && plist1 col == plist2 col
9. plist1 row < plist2 row && plist1 col< plist2 col

i cant organize the algorithm

Comment: Please consider changing the comments into English or removing altogether.

Comment: [Also **never** cast the return value of `malloc`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)! You're missing `#include <stdlib.h>`!

Comment: Additionally, you're passing in pointers of wrong type (`ListHeader *` vs `ListNode **`)

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to do and failing.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker either. My language also has some uncommon letters (though fewer than yours). I do not risk confusing compilers etc. by using them, not even in comments.